# simplest way to convert either a float or an int to the nearest integer in Python

Tags: python, math, type-conversion

I want to define a function that can take either an integer or a floating-point number as an argument, and return the nearest integer (i.e. the input argument itself if it is already an integer). I tried this:

```
 def toNearestInt(x):
    return int(x+0.5)
```

but it doesn't work for negative integers.

```
>>> toNearestInt(3)
3
>>> toNearestInt(3.0)
3
>>> toNearestInt(3.49)
3
>>> toNearestInt(3.50)
4
>>> toNearestInt(-3)
-2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python already has a builtin for this (more or less).

```
>>> round(-3, 0)
-3.0
>>> round(-3.5, 0)
-4.0
>>> round(-3.4, 0)
-3.0
>>> round(-4.5, 0)
-5.0
>>> round(4.5, 0)
5.0
```

Of course, you might want to wrap that in a call to `int`...

```
def toNearestInt(x):
    return int(round(x, 0))
```

Comment: I think i tried round(), but for the 0.5 boundaries, it always rounds away from zero, e.g. round(0.5) = 1.0, round(1.5) = 2.0, round(-0.5) = -1.0, round(-1.5) = -2.0

Comment: @JasonS -- When it's equally far from either value, then any choice you make is going to be arbitrary...

Comment: Not arbitrary. There are various techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking But you're right, it's a choice.

Comment: Anyway unless I'm doing nitpicky statistical stuff, yeah, it doesn't really matter so I'll go with your approach for simplicity.

Comment: @JasonS: In case the tie-breaking scheme *does* ever matter, you should also be aware that the behaviour [changed](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) between Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep your initial approach here and just check to see if the input is negative and add -0.5 in that case.

```
def toNearestInt(x):
    a = 0.5
    if x < 0:
        a*=-1
    return int(x+a)
```